# NodeJS and mongoose - find records from last hour

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

I am querying my MongoDB and I want to populate UI with 2 tables:

1. all records from db
2. current records, created within last hr

I am able to get all records, but the current record query  below is not working.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var myDate = new Date(Date.now() - 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    var curr = MyCollection.find(
        {_id: { $gt : myDate }}
    ).exec();

    MyCollection.find({}, function(err, doc) {
        res.render('index.jade', {latest: curr, all: doc}); //this query
    });
});
```

I am doing `{ _id: { $gt : myDate }}` but it does not return anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this post [Popping Timestamps into ObjectIds](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/12/20/querying-for-timestamps-using-objectids/), you need to convert the seconds from the timestamp to hexidecimal string first, something like the following:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var timestamp = new Date(Date.now() - 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var hexSeconds = Math.floor(timestamp/1000).toString(16);

    // Create an ObjectId with that hex timestamp
    var constructedObjectId = ObjectID(hexSeconds + "0000000000000000");
    console.log(constructedObjectId); // prints 564cd3810000000000000000
    MyCollection.find({}, function(err, doc) {
        MyCollection.find({
            "_id": { "$gt" : constructedObjectId }
        }, function (err, curr) {
            res.render('index.jade', { "latest": curr, "all": doc });
        });        
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  i tried but i get the same collection for 'curr' as 'doc'..

Comment: If you do a `console.log(ObjectID.createFromTime(Date.now()*1000 - 24*60*60))` and get the ObjectID, query the collection for that id, what do you get?

Comment: ahh.. i see why.  it returns '000000000000000000000000'.  why would it return all zeros?

Comment: My bad, was converting to milliseconds instead of seconds, try again this time. More from this post [Popping Timestamps into ObjectIds](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/12/20/querying-for-timestamps-using-objectids/)

Comment: thanks, i will read this article.. still getting zeros though. not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Give that another try, managed to fix the issue - need to convert secs to hexidecimal first